# Base conversion for array of fractional places

Tags: base-conversion

I am trying to implement an algorithm to convert an array of integers, which represent the digits of the fractional part of a number, from one base to another.  In other words:

```
int[] input = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}; // 0.00101 in base 2
int[] output = convertBase(input, 2, 10, 5); // convertBase(input, fromBase, toBase, precision)
output == {1, 5, 6, 2, 5}; // .15625 in base 10
```

There is a suggested algorithm, which is worded as such:

> for (i < precisionB):
>
> > 1. Keep a carry, initialize to 0.
> > 2. From RIGHT to LEFT
> >
> > > a. x = multiply the ith digit by baseB and add the carry
> > >       
> > > b. the new ith digit is x % baseA
> > >       
> > > c. carry = x / baseA
> > >
> > > output[i] = carry

But when I implement this, the second digit is always off by a bit for arrays that are longer than 3 digits.  For the above example, it'll return `{1, 3, 6, 2, 5}`.  An input of `{0, 1}` in base 2 will properly return `{2, 5}` in base 10.

I don't think I am properly understanding 2b.  It seems like you are already done with the ith digit in the input array, replacing it shouldn't matter?

Here is my code:

```
public static int[] convertBase(int[] digits, int baseA,
                                int baseB, int precisionB) {
    if (baseA < 2 | baseB < 2 | precisionB < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    int[] input = digits.clone();
    int[] output = new int[precisionB];
    int carry = 0;
    int j;
    int x;

    for (int i = 1; i <= precisionB; i++) {
        j = precisionB - i;
        if (input[j] >= baseA | input[j] < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        x = (input[j] * baseB) + carry;
        input[j] = x % baseA;
        carry = x / baseA;
        output[j] = carry;
    }

    return output;
}
```

This is from [MIT's 6.005](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-005-elements-of-software-construction-fall-2011/) course, problem set 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out.  The solution is that you must loop over all digits of the input array for each digit of the output.  Here's the code in Java:

```
public static int[] convertBase(int[] digits, int baseA,
                                int baseB, int precisionB) {
    if (baseA < 2 | baseB < 2 | precisionB < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    int[] input = digits.clone();
    int[] output = new int[precisionB];
    int carry;
    int j;
    int x;

    for (int i = 1; i <= precisionB; i++) {
        carry = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
            j = input.length - 1 - k;
            if (input[j] >= baseA | input[j] < 0) {
                return null;
            }
            x = (input[j] * baseB) + carry;
            input[j] = x % baseA;
            carry = x / baseA;
        }
        output[i-1] = carry;
    }
    return output;
}
```